# How to add user image in JSQMessageViewController Swift 4

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift4, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I'm using `JSQMessageViewController` for my Chat Application. Tried a lot to set incoming and outgoing message users image. If anybody using this library , Please help me to set user images.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the library is now deprecated for some reason. it w'd be better if you go for alternate method

Comment: can u show ur image i recently tried that lib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have to variables of type "JSQMessagesAvatarImage" on your "JSQMessagesViewController" one for sender and one for reciever. Before presenting your "JSQMessagesViewController" you can assign the images to these to variables using the JSQAvatarImageFactory initializer method that takes a UIImage and size , like this :

```
chatVc.senderImg = [JSQMessagesAvatarImageFactory avatarImageWithImage:senderImage diameter:80] 
chatVc.receiverImg = [JSQMessagesAvatarImageFactory avatarImageWithImage:receiverImage diameter:80]
```

than inside your "JSQMessagesViewController" in the dataSource method "avatarImageDataForItemAtIndexPath" you can return the sender or receiver avatar like this :

```
- (id<JSQMessageAvatarImageDataSource>)collectionView:(JSQMessagesCollectionView *)collectionView avatarImageDataForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

JSQMessage *message = [self.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];

if ([message.senderId isEqualToString:self.senderId])
    return _senderImg;
else
    return _receiverImg;}
```

This code is in objective-C , I don't have it in swift but I believe you can convert it into swift easily.

Comment: Yes.. I convert it.. Now its working for me. Thanks a lot

Comment: Glad to help mate :)

Comment: @ShahzaibQureshi bro i m facing index out of range when i delete item from chat page how could i resolve this

Comment: https://gist.github.com/diliptiwari333/b87b6e91c750c29149180559c0a2a4c7 check this bro @ShahzaibQureshi

Comment: this is chat message which is having all chat page data for both sender and receiver https://gist.github.com/diliptiwari333/16700bcb96ab66851b088e1a9d0cd1d3

Comment: on which line does it crash ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177351/discussion-between-dilip-tiwari-and-shahzaib-qureshi).

Comment: hiii @ShahzaibQureshi i want to implement JSQMessagesViewController using FireBase and it should be one to one communication